# Redhat Openshift 4 - Not able to make mysql connection from php pod to mysql pod

Tags: openshift

I am user of Openshift online and OKD. I am facing similar issue in both places. Please have a look.

1. I have created a project.
2. I have launched php in Developer's Catalog option. With other details, I entered my project's git url, project is cloned successfully. Now it needs to connect to mysql database only.
3. In Pods, I deployed mysql image from 'Deploy Image' option. It is launched successfully.
4. When I make mysql connection from php pod to mysql pod, it does not connect, connection time out.
   How should I make connection?

Note :
I do not have datastore option to launch mysql from developer's catalog in openshift online, that's why I am launching mysql image from deploy image.

Comment: For OpenShift Online, have you tried reaching out to https://help.openshift.com/forms/community-contact.html for help? Sometime it helps to have someone who can look directly at your project.

Comment: I had created a ticket there but I did not get any reply from them. I am using trial version of openshift and I am trying to understand its cluster structure. I feel it is quite difficult to host node, python based application here.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you are using Openshift Online and OKD and you are facing the issue at both places.

You can not create mysql from development store because currently, the OpenShift Online catalog does not provide MySQL template via the web interface directly, but you can deploy the MySQL template using the oc CLI instead. The database deployment is simplified when using templates.

Once logged in with the oc CLI, running

```
oc new-app -L
```

will list all of the templates that we were used to seeing in the web console, including the mysql-persistent. Then, you can specify all the template parameters via the oc CLI, e.g.:

```
oc new-app mysql-persistent -p MYSQL_USER=<desired_DB_username> -p MYSQL_PASSWORD=<mysql_password> -p MYSQL_DATABASE=<desired_database_name>
```

If you'd like to see all the supported template parameters, you can use

```
oc process <template_name> --parameters -n openshift
```

or, for a more detailed output,

```
oc describe template <template_name> -n openshift
```

Once the app is launched successfully, you can find this app's hostname in services and connect to it from your php pod after defining host name in php configuration file.